# Авторизация через Facebook на PHP. Возникает ошибка при обработке ответа от фейсбука

Tags: php, facebook

У меня возникает ошибка при обработке ответа от Facebook.
Ошибка возникает в токене. А что именно не так-непонятно.

Сформированная ссылка на вход есть в index.php, и выглядит так:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/v15.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?=ID?>&redirect_uri=<?=URL?>&response_type=code&scope=public_profile,email&state=123">Войти с Facebook</a>
```

Данные приложения есть в config.php, и выглядят так:

```
  <?php

define('ID','995258224659165');
define('SECRET','dd52c11eaf594c28928a5572b5');
define('URL', 'https://www.lvl3.top/create.php');

?>
```

Обработка ответа от Facebook есть в create.php, и выглядит так:

```
<?php

    echo "Вывод полученных данных пользователя:".'<br>';

if(!$_GET['code']){
exit('error code');
}
//var_dump($_GET['state']);


include 'config.php';
       $token=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token?client_id='.ID.'&redirect_uri='.URL.'&client_secret='.SECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code']),true );

if (!$token) {
    exit('error token');
}


      $data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/me?client_id='.ID.'&redirect_uri='.URL.'&client_secret='.SECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code'].'&access_token='.$token['access_token'].'&fields=id,email'),true );


if (!$data) {
    exit('error data');
}

var_dump($data);

?>
```

Ошибка - error token

Скриншот директории файлов прикладываю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видео прикладываю
http://somup.com/c3QFlNUA8c

Веб-сайт
https://www.lvl3.top/

Пользовался данным видео при создании кода:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQFEiEF21vY

Фото настроек приложения в Facebook прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как полностью выглядит ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Oшибка с токеном возникала потому что был неверный ключ приложения (secret) .

Также была ошибка после токена, в строке с запрососм $data.
Нужно было убрать слово oauth из запроса.

Было

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/me?client_id='.ID.'&redirect_uri='.URL.'&client_secret='.SECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code'].'&access_token='.$token['access_token'].'&fields=id,email'),true );
```

Стало

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?client_id='.ID.'&redirect_uri='.URL.'&client_secret='.SECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code'].'&access_token='.$token['access_token'].'&fields=id,email'),true );
```